# Does "Yet-not-something" exist?

Tags: adjectives, hyphens

I was writing a text and started thinking if this grammar construction exists: "yet-not-something".

The phrase I was trying to write is:

> It is expected the operations start by May and, by this time, any "yet-not-trained" staff takes training during operations.

I want to pass the idea that training has been running before the operations begin, but due to some reasons, some workers may not have taken it yet. It is different than only "non-trained staff".

If it is incorrect, what other way could I write it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're very close: the correct phrasing is **not-yet-trained**.

A good example of this is the phrase [This Film Is Not Yet Rated](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0493459/).

Another possible phrasing is "any staff (who have) **yet to be trained**".

Reference: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/somebody-something-has-yet-to-do-something